# Select row from a table by column value

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following:

```
animals = {{dog, black, 200}, {cat, white, 100}, {moose, brown, 500}, {zebra,black,100}}
```

If this came from a SQL table called animals, which has fields named:
type of animal, color, weight

I would say:

```sql
Select * from animals WHERE weight = 100
```

How do you do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Related: [(3916)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3916),
[(9269)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9269),
[(9702)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9702),
[(44256)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44256)

Comment: `GroupBy[animals, Last][100]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
animals={{dog,black,200},{cat,white,100},{moose,brown,500},{zebra,black,100}}

Cases[animals,{_,_,100}]

(*or*)

Select[animals,#[[3]]==100&]
```

Among others...

Comment: Thanks!... I am new to Mathematica and I am finding getting up to speed despite reading 5 books on it is hard.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: @DavidKerr: Have a look at q/a [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users). Both excellent mini-tutorials at this very site.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  So for say greater than 100 how would you do that in the Cases command? I figured out how to do in select. What does the # and & do in cases?

Comment: `Cases[animals,{_,_,x_/;x>100}]`. The `x` gives the placeholder a name you can then do things with (like test). The `#` and `&` in `Select` are placeholder (slot) and pure-function elements. Check the docs for `Select`, it covers it there.

Comment: Thanks. If you get pointed in the right direction with a few hints it gives geometric progress!