# deleting entire row if certain element is zero

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose, I have a list-

```
   data = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 5, 0}, {8, 9, 3}, {2, 5, 0}};
```

I want to delete second and fourth sublists for which third element of the row is zero. I can do this using

```
   DeleteCases[data,{_,_,0}];
```

How can the same operation be achieved efficiently if the list contains a large number of elements instead of just 3?

Comment: That depends on where the zero is going to be.  E.g. the third element, the last element or some other position.  But probably the pattern `__` (`BlankSequence[]`) is what you are after.

Comment: [45429](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45429/5478) but use `DeleteCases`.

Comment: Maybe not the most efficient, but incredibly convenient: `data /. {_, 
_, 0} -> Nothing`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `data` is packed, then the fastest will probably be

```
Pick[data, Unitize@data[[All, m]], 1]
```

where `m` is the position where you don't allow a 0. If it is the last element in a row, then you can use -1 for `m`.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
Clear[unitize, pick, n, data]
RandomSeed[1];
n = -1;
data = RandomChoice[Range[0, 10], {10^8, 3}];

AbsoluteTiming[Pick[data, Unitize@data[[All, n]], 1] // Length]

unitize[x_] := unitize[x] = Unitize[x]
pick[xs_, sel_, patt_] := pick[xs] = Pick[xs, sel, patt]
AbsoluteTiming[pick[data, unitize@data[[All, n]], 1] // Length]
```

Out:

```
{7.3081, 90913401}
{5.87919, 90913401}
```

Comment: -1, this doesn't answer the question. The solution would be fine if instead of `AnyTrue` you had `nthTrue`, but `nthTrue` is not a built-in.

Comment: Fair enough. I optimised it base on Marius's method.

Comment: un-downvoted, but this is essentially identical to the accepted answer + some very odd memoization technique, which I'm not sure what is achieving here. You know, your original approach would have easily been doable as `Select[data, #[[n]] != 0 &]`. As an aside, I see you using memoization in many of your recent answers, why do you utilize it so heavily?

Comment: In Functional Programming, we call it Pure Function, It's NOT Pure Function in Wolfram Language. Pure Functions in Wolfram Language is just anonymous functions. When I know that a function has no side effect, such as File System, Network, I implement it as a Pure Function(Functional Programming term).

Comment: The pure function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices (usually—see below).
Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

Comment: `f[x] := f[x] = (* stuff *)` mutates the definition of `f`. This has nothing to do with pure functions, this is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). But in your code saying `pick[xs_, sel_, patt_] := pick[xs] = Pick[xs, sel, patt]` does literally nothing, but add an extra level of complexity. With every call you update teh value of `pick[xs]`, but it is *never* called!

Comment: Besides that, this `unitize[x_] := unitize[x] = Unitize[x]` is simply harmful, unless we *know* that `unitize` will be called many times with exactly the same argument. Now the kernel is wasting time comparing an input to a possibly large list stored in the `DownValues` instead of just getting on with `Unitize`ing.

Comment: The optimised method is faster. The execution time of unoptimised method is 7.3081, the optimised one's execution time is 5.87919.

Comment: I have seen two `AbsoluteTiming`s in a row return one result, then insert the next immediately *before* the first. My run of your code had your method almost twice a slow as the built-ins. Split the timings into two input cells and run them separately.

Comment: This is what I see on my machine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPaGP.png

Comment: I tested it on my another machine. The optimised one is still faster. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3d4k.png

Comment: Could this be related to caching? Perhaps throwing in a `ClearSystemCache[]` would restore the expected behavior. If not, this is worth a separate question.

Comment: Function Clear is enough. Anyway, I added ClearSystemCache[] and tested it again. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOP8h.png

Comment: I honestly have no idea, why this happens. Your application of `ClearSystemCache[]` is not what I had in mind, I thought, perhaps, something was being cached after the first call to `Pick`, so I tried to put the `ClearSystemCache` between `Pick` and `pick`. No effect. My machine at work has, apparently, less cores and memory than yours, so I tried smaller inputs (between `10^7` and `5*10^7` rows). `pick` was very slightly, but consistently faster, much to my surprise. However today I cannot reproduce this reliably; (see next comment)

Comment: with this code: `$HistoryLength = 0; Table[
 Clear[pick, unitize, data];
 unitize[x_] := unitize[x] = Unitize[x];
 pick[xs_, sel_, patt_] := pick[xs] = Pick[xs, sel, patt];
 data = RandomChoice[Range[0, 10], {i*10^7, 3}];
 {Pick[data, Unitize@data[[All, -1]], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First,
  pick[data, unitize@data[[All, -1]], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First},
 {i, 5}]` I now get `{{0.466588, 0.465504}, {0.924702, 0.929265}, {1.3835, 
  1.40883}, {1.8459, 1.90577}, {2.30805, 2.44937}}` i.e. `Pick` is consistently faster.

Comment: Well. now the behavior is back. Please drop by the thread [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145286/26956)