# Inserting data into a mathlink slave kernel via Table

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I'm trying to perform a computation that will:

1. Be long on my machine (I estimate 24-48 hours)
2. Consume a lot of memory
3. Generate ~1 gig of data at the end

To manage the calculation I'd like to chunk it out, send it over mathlink to a slave kernel, do the computation, export the output, then quit and restart the slave kernel.  This method has been discussed several times here and I've mostly relied on the posts [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145852/how-to-automatically-do-a-computation-quit-restart-and-do-a-new-computation/145941#145941), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864643/self-restarting-mathkernel-is-it-possible-in-mathematica), and [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/971065).

A minimal example of my problem can be shown with a simplified version of newKernelEvaluate from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145852/how-to-automatically-do-a-computation-quit-restart-and-do-a-new-computation/145941#145941).

```
ClearAll[newKernelEvaluate];
Attributes[newKernelEvaluate] = HoldAll;
newKernelEvaluate[expr_] := Module[{link, result},
   link = LinkLaunch[First@$CommandLine <> "  -subkernel"];
   LinkRead[link];
   LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket@expr];
   result = LinkRead@link;
   LinkClose@link;
   Replace[result, ReturnPacket@x_ :> x]];
```

I'd like to wrap a Table in newKernelEvaluate and then wrap it with another Table.  Like:

```
Table[ newKernelEvaluate[ Table[i, {i, j}]], {j, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}]
```

On my machine, the response I get is:

> {MessagePacket[Table, "iterb"], MessagePacket[Table, "iterb"]}

But, I think I can get data into the slave kernel via this method because this works:

```
Table[newKernelEvaluate[k = j; k], {j, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

---

Not sure if this helps, but a bit more info about my specific problem.  This is closer to what I've been working with:

```
Table[
 
 kernel = 
  LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -subkernel", 
   LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];
 LinkRead[kernel];
 LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[qfrange = Range[qnum, qnum + 2]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[nrange = Range[num, num + 2*5, 5]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, 
  Unevaluated[\[Sigma]range = 
    Sqrt[Range[\[Sigma]num, \[Sigma]num + 2*.05, .05]]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, 
  Unevaluated[
   Table[Module[{}, {qf, n, \[Sigma]}], {qf, qfrange}, {n, 
     nrange}, {\[Sigma], \[Sigma]range}]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[Quit[]]];
 ,
 {qnum, {20, 23}},
 {num, {70, 85}},
 {\[Sigma]num, {1, 1.15}}
 ]
```

The table in this line:

```
LinkWrite[kernel, 
  Unevaluated[
   Table[Module[{}, {qf, n, \[Sigma]}], {qf, qfrange}, {n, 
     nrange}, {\[Sigma], \[Sigma]range}]]];
```

Contains a Module that will hold the calculation.  As it happens, this bit of code works as expected on my machine, but when I add any functions that depend on the iterators in the inner Table it errors out.  For example, this will send back error messages:

```
Table[
 
 kernel = 
  LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -subkernel", 
   LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];
 LinkRead[kernel];
 LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[qfrange = Range[qnum, qnum + 2]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[nrange = Range[num, num + 2*5, 5]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, 
  Unevaluated[\[Sigma]range = 
    Sqrt[Range[\[Sigma]num, \[Sigma]num + 2*.05, .05]]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, 
  Unevaluated[
   Table[Module[{a}, a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]; a], {qf, 
     qfrange}, {n, nrange}, {\[Sigma], \[Sigma]range}]]];
 Print[LinkRead[kernel]];
 LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[Quit[]]];
 ,
 {qnum, {20, 23}},
 {num, {70, 85}},
 {\[Sigma]num, {1, 1.15}}
 ]
```

Also, just incase it's relevant:

```
$Version
```

> "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Thanks for any help.