# Implement the Bisection algorithm elegantly and easily

Tags: equation-solving, programming, numerics, algorithm

#### Description:

Rencently, I have finished my course **Numerical Analysis**, so I'd like to implement many algorithm that I have learned from that course.By this practice, I hope that I can improve my `programming skill` and understand the knowledge of `numerical analysis` deeply.

Firstly,I implement the **bisection** to search the root of nonlinear equation

#### My trial

```
shrinkInterval[func_, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}] /; a < b :=
 Module[{interval},
  interval = {a, (a + b)/2, b};
  Last@
   Flatten[
    Select[
     Thread@
     (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@
      {Sign /@ (func /@ interval), interval}), 
     Times @@ (First@#) < 0 &], 1]
 ]
(*=====================================================*)
biSection[func_, {a0_?NumericQ, b0_?NumericQ}, \[Xi]_?NumericQ] :=
 NestWhile[
  shrinkInterval[func, #] &, {a0, b0}, Abs@(Subtract @@ #) > \[Xi] &]
```

**Testing**

```
biSection[#^3 + 4 #^2 - 10 &, {1, 1.5`20}, .5*10^-15]
```

> ```
> {1.3652300134140964438, 1.3652300134140968879}
> ```

#### My question:

1, In my code, I think the function **`shrinkInterval`** is a little complex. I'd like
to know more simple method to rewrite it?

2, Is there any good form/strategy to deal with the below condition that I need to write `NumericQ` many times?

```
myfun[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ,z_NumericQ},{a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ},
  {c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ}]...
```

Comment: Your algorithm seems to fail if you "accidentally" find an exact root in the bisection process

Comment: [Something related](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html). Just to note a common problem with bisection methods and how to fix it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### 1. Bisection algorithm

The algorithm itself is fairly straightforward and "fast" in some sense: the number of iterations is roughly `Log2` of the ratio of the initial interval length and the desired accuracy.  My point is that the time spent by `Flatten`, `Select`, `Thread`, etc. in your function is fairly small.  The significant time-waster is reevaluating the function at the end points of the interval at each iteration.  These were evaluated in the previous step and discarded.  So you end up with three times as many evaluations of `func` as necessary.  For a function like

```
func = #^3 - 4 #^2 - 10 &
```

which is really fast to evaluate, it's not much of a big deal.  But for a complicated function like

```
func[t_?NumericQ] := 1 + NIntegrate[Sin[x^2] - x, {x, 0, t}]
```

it makes a big difference.

Since you apparently want something *Mathematica*-like, as opposed to a procedural loop, here's a take on it.  Note, as [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius) commented, we really ought to check whether the exact root has accidentally been found.  That adds some case-checking.  I'll discuss pattern-checking the arguments later.  You may note I defined a `realQ` to replace `NumericQ`.  This may be over-fastidious, but complex numbers will not work.

To address the problem of repeated function evaluations, I added the signs to the data being nested.  So instead of just an interval `{a, b}` being passed, I now have

```
{{a, sgna}, {b, sgnb}}
```

being passed. I used `DeleteDuplicatesBy` to delete the old element with the same sign of `func` at the midpoint.  Since the midpoint comes first, the old one will be deleted.  The order of `a` and `b` does not matter, so `splitInterval` ignores it.  The top function `biSection2` orders the final output.

```
splitInterval[func_, v : {{a_, sgna_}, {b_, sgnb_}}] := 
 With[{sgn = Sign[func[(a + b)/2]]},
  If[sgn == 0,
   {{(a + b)/2, sgn}, {(a + b)/2, sgn}},
   DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[{{(a + b)/2, sgn}}, v], Last]]  (* see Pre V10 note at bottom *)
  ]

ClearAll[biSection2];
realQ = Quiet@Check[BooleanQ[# < 0], False] &;
biSection2[func_, {a0_?realQ, b0_?realQ}, ξ_?realQ] := 
 With[{sgna = Sign[func[a0]], sgnb = Sign[func[b0]]},
  Which[
    sgna == 0
    , {a0, a0},
    sgnb == 0
    , {b0, b0},
    True
    , Sort[
     First /@ 
      NestWhile[splitInterval[func, #] &, {{a0, sgna}, {b0, sgnb}}, 
       Abs@(Subtract @@ #[[All, 1]]) > ξ &]]
    ] /; sgna*sgnb <= 0
  ]
```

Example, and comparison with OP's `biSection`:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

func[t_?NumericQ] := 1 + NIntegrate[Sin[x^2] - x, {x, 0, t}];

(op = biSection[func, {1, 2.`20}, 10^-14]) // AccurateTiming
(me = biSection2[func, {1, 2.`20}, 10^-14]) // AccurateTiming
op - me
(*
  0.530108
  0.186535
  {0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20}
*)
```

#### 2. Pattern checking

There are several questions that deal with this issue on the site.  Some are listed below.  Some deal with related issues such as generating error messages as well as with argument checking.  Some deal with the use of [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`), which appears at the end of the definition of `biSection2`.  The ones marked with an asterisk address nearly the same question as the OP's question 2.

> [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching)
>   [_?NumericQ equivalent for lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/numericq-equivalent-for-lists)
>   [How to program a F::argx message?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/how-to-program-a-fargx-message)
>   *[More elegant way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44256/more-elegant-way)
>   *[Quick way to use conditioned patterns when defining multi-argument function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52057/quick-way-to-use-conditioned-patterns-when-defining-multi-argument-function)
>   *[How shortening argument test when declaring functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68866/how-shortening-argument-test-when-declaring-functions)

Let me just make a few remarks about the choices represented above.

If `shrinkInterval` or `splitInterval` is to be used only internally by `biSection`, one might put the responsibility of checking the arguments on `biSection`.  If the argument checks were significantly time-consuming and `shrinkInterval` were iterated many times, it might make sense for the sake of efficiency to do this.  This is the approach in the code above, even though `?NumericQ` is very fast and the number of iterations not very great.

The `Condition` `/; sgna*sgnb <= 0` inside `With` in the definition of `biSection2` checks the condition after `sgna` and `sgnb` have been computed and before the `Which` statement is evaluated.  If the condition is not true, then the evaluation of `bisection2` halts and returns the unevaluated expression.  See the documentation and the linked questions for more information.  Checking the arguments is safer, and should be considered required if the function is meant to be standalone and available to users; however, it is not uncommon to have a user-level function that checks the arguments and then calls an internal function.

**Three fun ways to handle `myfun` gleaned from the linked questions**:

I usually copy-paste-paste-paste for this, but I rarely have more than four or five arguments that need it.  Instead of `myfun[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, {c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ}]`, you could...

---

```
ClearAll[myfun];
myfun[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] /; 
  VectorQ[{x, y, z, a, b, c, d}, NumericQ] := 
 Total /@ {{x, y, z}, {a, b}, {c, d}}
```

---

```
ClearAll[myfun, allNumericQ];
SetAttributes[allNumericQ, HoldAllComplete];
allNumericQ[f_[args__]] := VectorQ[Flatten[{args}], NumericQ];  (* caveat Flatten *)
myfun[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_}, {c_, d_}]?allNumericQ := 
 Total /@ {{x, y, z}, {a, b}, {c, d}}
```

---

```
ClearAll[myfun];
myfun[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] /; TrueQ[$inmyfun] := 
 Total /@ {{x, y, z}, {a, b}, {c, d}};
myfun[args___] := Block[{$inmyfun = True},
 myfun[args]] /; ! TrueQ[$inmyfun] && VectorQ[Flatten[{args}], NumericQ];
```

---

All the above work as follows:

```
myfun[{1, 2, 3}, {4, Sqrt[5]}, {6., 7}]
(*  {6, 4 + Sqrt[5], 13.}  *)

myfun[{1, x, 3}, {4, Sqrt[5]}, {6., 7}]
(*  myfun[{1, x, 3}, {4, Sqrt[5]}, {6., 7}]  *)
```

**Caveat:** Beware using `allNumericQ` if the `args` might contain a large amount of data.

---

#### Pre V10 users

For users of V9 and earlier, you can use these replacements for `DeleteDuplicatesBy` and `BooleanQ`.  The code for `DeleteDuplicatesBy` below is basically Mr.Wizard's `myDeDupeBy` in his answer to his question, [DeleteDuplicatesBy is not performing as I'd hoped. Am I missing something?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/deleteduplicatesby-is-not-performing-as-id-hoped-am-i-missing-something/55295#55295)  Perhaps everyone should be using it.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[x_, f_] := GatherBy[x, f][[All, 1]]

BooleanQ = MatchQ[#, True | False] &
```

Comment: Dear Michael E2,Thanks for your detailed answer sincerely:). And I have understood your idea about implementation of *Bisection*.Owing to that I didn't have MMA 10, so I cannot run the function *BooleanQ, DeleteDuplicatesBy and Needs["GeneralUtilities"]*,So according to your idea, I replaced the   `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[{{(a + b)/2, sgn}}, v], Last]` to `Delete[Insert[v, {(a + b)/2, sgn}, 2], sgn]]`. Do you think it is efficient?

Comment: @ShutaoTang You're welcome.  I added my recommendations for replacements for `DeleteDuplicatesBy` and `BooleanQ`.  I did not test your `Delete` version, but I do not think it will work if the function is increasing near the root.  (Instead of ``GeneralUtilities`AccurateTiming``, use `AbsoluteTiming`.)

Answer (score 9):

In the following well known implementation of `biSection`, the use of `shrinkInterval` is not needed. Of course your \[Xi] has to be positive. My condition on the input is a little bit stronger and makes the use of `NumericQ` superfluous.

```
biSection[ func_, {a_, b_}, eps_?Positive] /; func[a]func[b]<0 :=
   Module[ {c, d, e},
    {c,d}= If[func[a]>0, {b,a}, {a,b}];
    While[d-c>eps,
      With[{e=(c+d)/2},
        If[func[e]<0, c=e, d=e]]
     ];
     {c,d}
   ]

biSection[#^3+4 #^2-10&,{1,1.5`20},.5*10^-15]

(* {1.3652300134140964438,1.3652300134140968879} *)
```

**UPDATE**

After almost one and a half year, when someone upvoted this answer, I had another look at this solution and found that it is obviously incorrect when `d` is less than `c`. This can trivially be repaired by replacing `While[d-c>eps` with `While[Abs[d-c]>eps`, or by using the following variant:

```
biSection[func_,{a_,b_},eps_?Positive]/;(a<b && func[a]func[b]<0):=
  Module[{c=a,d=b}, With[{test=If[func[a]>0, Greater, Less]},
    While[d-c>eps,With[{e=(c+d)/2},If[test[func[e],0],c=e,d=e]]];
    {c,d}]]

biSection[#^3+4 #^2-10&,{1,1.5`20},.5*10^-15]
biSection[-(#^3+4 #^2-10)&,{1,1.5`20},.5*10^-15]

(* {1.3652300134140964438,1.3652300134140968879} *)
(* {1.3652300134140964438,1.3652300134140968879} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is quite old, but here's my attempt. It's as fast as Michael's, but much simpler:

```
Bisection[f_, int_, tol_, niter_] := Block[
  {m = tol + 1, prev, ym, yl = f[Last@int]},
  NestWhile[(
     prev = m;
     m = Total@#/2;
     ym = f[m];
     If[ym*yl > 0, yl = ym; {First@#, m}, {m, Last@#}]
     ) &,
   int,  ym != 0 && Abs[m - prev] > tol &, 2, niter]
  ]
```

Testing it with

```
func[t_?NumericQ] := 1 + NIntegrate[Sin[x^2] - x, {x, 0, t}];

Bisection[func, {1, 2.`20}, 10^-14, 1000] // Timing
{0.109375, {1.9252809180739163253, 1.9252809180739234307}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Attributes@bisection = {HoldAll};
bisection::nochangeofsign = "sign does not change, try other bounds";
Options@bisection = {AccuracyGoal -> $MachinePrecision/2, 
   Rational -> False};
Clear@bisection; 
bisection[expr_, {x_, x1_, x2_}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{f1 = Function[x, #] &@expr},
  With[{s = 
     Which[LessEqual @@ #, 1, GreaterEqual @@ #, -1, True, 
        Message@bisection::nochangeofsign] &@{f1@x1, 0, f1@x2}},
   If[Not@OptionValue@Rational, 1., 1] First@
     NestWhile[
      If[s f1@#2 > 0, {First@#, #2}, {#2, Last@#}] &[#, 
        Total@#/2] &, {x1, x2}, 
      Abs[First@# - Last@#] > 
        Power[10, -OptionValue@AccuracyGoal] &]]]
```

I think it is not good to use constants or variables in the core of the program: my experience is that it is slower (and it is also ugly).  Please someone do the Timing and try to improve.

As the result is Rational, it is a good idea to keep Rational in Options just in case the user needs Rational approximation.

Usage:

```
bisection[Cos@x - x, {x, 0, 1.5}]

bisection[-Cos@x + .8, {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
 Rational -> True]
```

This is a funny example:

```
bisection[Tan[x/4] - 1, {x, 3, 4}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
 Rational -> True]
```

Comment: I think that the `NumericQ` question is solved by the `HoldAll`.

Answer (score 0):

My program is not bad but has design flaws: the Rational option is useless and the interface will fail in certain cases.  So I need to update:

```
Attributes@bisection = {HoldAll};
bisection::nochangeofsign = "sign does not change, try other bounds";
Options@bisection = {AccuracyGoal -> $MachinePrecision/2, 
   Sow -> False};
Clear@bisection; 
bisection[expr_, {x_, x1_, x2_}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Catch@If[OptionValue@Sow, {First@#, First@Last@#} &, First]@
   Reap@With[{sign = 
       Which[LessEqual @@ #, 1, GreaterEqual @@ #, -1, True, 
          Message@bisection::nochangeofsign] &@(*Throw@*){ReleaseHold[
          Hold@expr /. x -> x1], 0, 
         ReleaseHold[Hold@expr /. x -> x2]}},
     If[OptionValue@Sow, #, First@#] &@
      With[{hook = If[OptionValue@Sow, Sow, Identity]}, 
       NestWhile[
        If[sign ReleaseHold[Hold@expr /. x -> hook@#2] > 
             0, {First@#, #2}, {#2, Last@#}] &[#, Total@#/2] &, {x1, 
         x2}, Abs[First@# - Last@#] > 
          Power[10, -OptionValue@AccuracyGoal] &]]]
```

Usage:

```
bisection[-Cos@x + x, {x, 0, 1.5}, Sow -> True]
```

This example is fun:

```
bisection[x*x - 2, {x, 1, 2}, AccuracyGoal -> 20]
```

Comparing this version with the former does not teach anything on numerical analysis but it teaches a bit on the Wolfram language.