# A problem about Steffensen method

Tags: equation-solving, programming, algorithm, nonlinear

Two days ago,I asked a question about bisection algorithm. Thanks for [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) giving me a good [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69771/implement-the-bisection-algorithm-elegantly-and-easily/69783#69783)

**My algorithm**

1, I use the bisection algorithm to generate a initial value that contain a root of a nonlinear equation.

2,Then I use the `Steffensen method` and initial value to iterate

3,Lastly,I can achieve a convergent sequence.

**Steffensen method**

$$\psi (x)=x-\frac{[\phi (x)-x]^2}{\phi (\phi (x))-2\phi (x)+x}$$

**Implementation**

```
splitInterval[func_, v : {{a_, sgna_}, {b_, sgnb_}}] := 
 With[{sgn = Sign[func[(a + b)/2]]},
  If[sgn == 0,
   {{(a + b)/2, sgn}, {(a + b)/2, sgn}},
   Join[
    DeleteCases[v, {_, sgn}], {{(a + b)/2, sgn}}]
   ]
  ] 
(*==============================================================*)
biSection[ func_, {a0_?NumericQ, b0_?NumericQ}, ε_?NumericQ] :=
 With[
  {sgna = Sign[func[a0]], sgnb = Sign[func[b0]]},
  Which[
   sgna == 0, {a0, a0},
   sgnb == 0, {b0, b0},
   True,
   Sort@
    (First /@
      NestWhile[
       splitInterval[func, #] &, {{a0, sgna}, {b0, sgnb}}, 
       Abs@(Subtract @@ #[[All, 1]]) > ε &])] /; 
  sgna*sgnb <= 0
 ]
```

---

```
steffensenMethod[func_, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, ε_?NumericQ] :=
 With[
  {φ = # + func[#] &,
   ini = First@biSection[func, {a, b}, .5*10^-3]},
  NestWhileList[
   # - (φ[#] - #)^2/(φ[φ[#]] - 2 φ[#] + #) &, ini,
   Abs[#1 - #2] > ε &, 2]
]
```

**Testing**

```
steffensenMethod[ Cos[#] - # &, {-1, 1.5`20}, .5*10^-15] // TableForm
```

> [image]

```
steffensenMethod[ #^3 + 4 #^2 - 10 &, {-1, 1.5`25}, .5*10^-15] // TableForm
```

[image]

---

```
steffensenMethod[(# - 2) Exp[#] - 1 &, {2, 3`25}, 10^-9] // TableForm
```

> Normal result

**Question**

I did't know why it appear this case. and I'd like to know that is it possible to deal with this problem?

#### Update

Thanks for  *@Daniel Lichtblau*'s analysis.
[image]

So I add a criterion to terminate the iteration process.

```
steffensenUpdate[func_, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, ε_?NumericQ] :=
 With[
  {φ = # + func[#] &,
   ini = First@biSection[func, {a, b}, .5*10^-3]},
  NestWhileList[
   # - (φ[#] - #)^2/(φ[φ[#]] - 2 φ[#] + #) &, ini,
   Abs[#1 - #2] > ε && (φ[φ[#]] - 2 φ[#] + #) > 10^-20 &, 2]
 ]
```

---

```
steffensenUpdate[#^3 + 4 #^2 - 10 &, {-1, 1.5`25}, .5*10^-15] // TableForm
steffensenUpdate[Cos[#] - # &, {-1, 1.5`20}, .5*10^-15] // TableForm
```

> [image]

However, I didin't know how to determine the **value** in the criterion  (φ[φ[#]] - 2 φ[#] + #) > 10^-20.

Comment: Although its output is voluminous, `Trace` might be helpful.

Comment: This looks to be the sort of change I was advocating. One thing though: compare the absolute value of the denominator to your chosen epsilon: if it's negative, but large in magnitude, you won't want to stop the iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may help to indicate what goes wrong.

```
steffensenMethodB[
  func_, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, ε_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{φ, ini = First@biSection[func, {a, b}, .5*10^-3], f, g},
  φ[x_] := x + func[x];
  f[x_] := -(φ[x] - x)^2;
  g[x_] := (φ[φ[x]] - 2 φ[x] + x);
  NestWhileList[(Print[{#, f[#], g[#]}]; # + f[#]/g[#]) &, ini, 
   Abs[#1 - #2] > ε &, 2, 8]]

steffensenMethodB[
  Cos[#] - # &, {-1, 1.5}, .5*10^-15]

During evaluation of In[17]:= {0.7388916015625, -1.049002366032748*^-7, -0.0005420470223734819}

During evaluation of In[17]:= {0.739085127644691, -8.691469255444763*^-17, -1.5602758529631444*^-8}

During evaluation of In[17]:= {0.7390851332151607, 0., 0.}

During evaluation of In[17]:= Power::infy:Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[17]:= Infinity::indet:Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>

(* Out[17]= TableForm[{0.7388916015625, 0.739085127644691, 
  0.7390851332151607, Indeterminate}] *)
```

You get a new denominator of 0 (numerator also) before the past two iterates are within epsilon. You might need to rewrite, possibly along the lines above, to include this possibility in the stopping criterion.

Comment: Dear Daniel Lichtblau, Thanks for your analysis, and I have  updated my question.