# A method for endpoints in mathemtica

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, algorithm, multivalued

If $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$ is a real line, $C$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $K(C)$ denote set of a compact subset of $C$. Define a multivalued mapping $T:C\rightarrow K(C)$. We know that a point $p\in C$ is called an enpoint of $T$ if $Tp=\{p\}$. Suppose for $x\in X$, we set $R(x,C)=\max\{|x-y|:y\in C\}$. Now let $C=[0,1]$ and $T:C\rightarrow K(C)$ be $Tx=[0,1]$. Then $p=0$ is a unique endpoint of $T$. I want to find the value by the following iteration method: $x_{0}=0.5\in C$, $a_{n}=0.8$ and set
$x_{n+1}=(1-\alpha_{n})x_{n}+\alpha_{n}u_{n},$

where $u_{n}\in Tx_{n}$ such that $|u_{n}-x_{n}|=R(x_{n},Tx_{n})$.
I set the following code in mathmetica:

```
T[x_] := T[x] = [0, x]
a[n_] := a[n] = 0.8;
x[0] = 0.5;
D(x,T[x])=max{Abs[x-y]:y\[Epsilon] T[x]};
u[n]\[Epsilon] Tx[n] such that Abs[u[n]-x[n]]=R(x[n],T[x[n]]);
x[n_] := x[n] = (1 - a[n - 1]) x[n - 1] + a[n - 1] u[n-1]
NumberForm[a1 = {Table[x[i],{i, 0, 9}]}, 5]
```

I know there will be several mistakes in my code to which doest run the code because Im not too much expert in mathemtica. I will thank if any one improve my code (or suggest a new method to define it) too achieve my target.

Comment: `D` is a system symbol for the (partial) derivative. `( ... ,  ... )` is a syntax error. `[0, x]` is a syntax error. `Abs[x, y]` makes no sense to me.  The colon following it is improper use of `Pattern`. The phrase `such that` in the code suggests you need to proofread the question, unless `such` and `that` are variables being multiplied. In short, you need to spend some time with an introduction to Mathematica and learn the basic syntax and features of the language — maybe you have since Feb 28, in which case you should post revised code. Or hire a programmer to do the coding for you.

Comment: Dear @Michael I know that there will be several in my code. I think the code can be made using an idea https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113795/how-to-find-roots-using-the-bisection-method

Comment: But Im not a too much expert in mathematica that why I posted it here.

Comment: Did you mean to define $T$ like this: $T x = [0,x]$?

Answer (score 3):

```
x0 = 0.5;
\[Alpha] = 0.8;
T = Function[x, Interval[{0, x}]];
u = Function[x, With[{ends = MinMax[T[x]]},
    ends[[Ordering[Abs[ends - x], -1][[1]]]]
    ]];
FixedPointList[
 Function[x, (1 - \[Alpha]) x + \[Alpha] u[x]],
 x0,
 SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 1*^-12 &)
 ]
```

> `{0.5, 0.1, 0.02, 0.004, 0.0008, 0.00016, 0.000032, 6.4*10^-6,  1.28*10^-6, 2.56*10^-7, 5.12*10^-8, 1.024*10^-8, 2.048*10^-9,  4.096*10^-10, 8.192*10^-11, 1.6384*10^-11, 3.2768*10^-12,  6.5536*10^-13, 1.31072*10^-13}`

Comment: Dear @Henrik the code you suggested is pretty best. However, It not run in my PC. Is there any thing missed here?

Comment: Maybe `|->` was the reason. I changed all its occurrences to `Function`. Please try again.