# Is there any other way to find roots of a non-monotonic function?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics

I have the relation of $k$ and $w$, and now I need to plot $k$ vs $w$($k\sim 10^7$, $w\sim 10^{13}$). The relation is given as follows:

parameters:

```
\[Epsilon][2] = \[Epsilon][1] = 9.5; \[Epsilon][3] = 1;\[Mu] = 1.257*10^-6;c = 3.*10^8;\[Epsilon]0 = 8.85*10^-12;d = 20.*10^-9;
\[Sigma] = Im[1/(-I* w)*Abs[(7.5*10^14*(1.6*10^-19)^2)/(0.2*0.91*10^-30)]];
```

relation:

```
1 - ((\[Epsilon][1] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][2] w^2/c^2 + k^2] - \[Epsilon][
    2] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][1] w^2/c^2 + 
    k^2] - \[Sigma] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][1] w^2/c^2 + k^2]
    Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][2] w^2/c^2 + 
     k^2]/(\[Epsilon]0  w ))/(\[Epsilon][
    1] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][2] w^2/c^2 + k^2] + \[Epsilon][
    2] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][1] w^2/c^2 + 
    k^2] - \[Sigma] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][1] w^2/c^2 + k^2]
    Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][2] w^2/c^2 + 
     k^2]/(\[Epsilon]0  w ))) (\[Epsilon][
 3] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][2] w^2/c^2 + k^2] - \[Epsilon][
 2] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][3] w^2/c^2 + k^2])/(\[Epsilon][
 3] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][2] w^2/c^2 + k^2] + \[Epsilon][
 2] Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][3] w^2/c^2 + k^2])Exp[-2 d Sqrt[-\[Epsilon][2] w^2/c^2 + k^2]]=0
```

The method `ContourPlot` doesn't work well, so I turn to use `FindRoot` and `NSolve` to find the list of solutions $(k,w)$ so I can plot it manually. However, even `FindRoot` doesn't work well. For example, when I set `w=3 Pi * 10 ^12`, the solution of k should be $k=1.41179*10^8$. However, I cannot use `FindRoot` to find this solution since the LHS of the relation is a non-monotonic function: [image]
Now I have to choose the value of k0 very carefully for `FindRoot` to start with, or Mathematica cannot give me the correct answer. However, what I need to do is to plot the relation between $k$ and $w$, so I really don't want to find k0 by looking into the plot with different $w$ one by one, I hope to find a way to make Mathematica smartly choose k0 and find the solution.

I am grateful for any help, thank you!

Comment: Might be a good application of the [bisection method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69771/implement-the-bisection-algorithm-elegantly-and-easily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is to enlist `NDSolve` to solve your equation as a DAE:

```
ksol = First@
   NDSolveValue[{
      obj == 0 /. k -> k[w],   (* obj = OP's "relation" w/o "= 0" *)
      k[3 Pi*10^12] == (k /. FindRoot[obj /. w -> 3 Pi*10^12, {k, 1.4*^8}]),
      y'[w] == 0, y[3 Pi*10^12] == 0},      (* dummy ODE *)
    {k}, {w, 1*^12, 3 Pi*10^12}, StartingStepSize -> 1];
                                 (* N.B. step size >> 3 Pi*10^12 * $MachineEpsilon *)

ListLinePlot[ksol, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If greater precision is desired, you can use `ksol` to estimate initial values for `FindRoot`.

Comment: excellent, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any essential difference between `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue`?

Comment: @JieyuYou `NDSolveValue[ODE, y, {x, a, b}, options]` and `y /. NDSolve[ODE, y, {x, a, b}, options]` are completely equivalent.  The difference is the form of the return value and how you use it.  I tend to prefer `NDSolve`, esp. for systems with multiple dependent variable or multiple solutions. More and more I see experienced users saying they prefer `NDSolveValue`, which is convenient for DEs of the form `y'[x] == f[x, y[x]]`.