# Unable to implement bisection method using recursion

Tags: recursion, core-language

I have tried to implement a bisection method for finding roots using `SetAttributes[BisectionItt, HoldAll]` and then `SetAttributes[BisectionItt, First]`; both to no avail. I have tried reading up on the issue, but I can't seem to implement anything that works.

I want a function implementing the following form:

> Bisection[left initial, right initial, function, number of iterations] -> estimate of root

Here is my code:

```
Bisection[a0_, b0_, function_, itt_] :=
  Module[{},
    a = N[a0];
    b = N[b0];
    m = (a+b)/2;
    If[function[m] > 0, a = m, b = m];
    If[itt  < 0, 
      Return[m],
      Return[Bisection[a, b, function, itt--]]];]

f[x_] := x^3 - 5 x + 1;
Bisection[0, 1, f, 7]
```

I believe that this a pass by value/reference issue. I would be very grateful if someone could show me a working example.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69771/implement-the-bisection-algorithm-elegantly-and-easily

Answer (score 0):

Running your code produces the error `Decrement::rvalue: 7 is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed.`  That made me look at the `itt--` part.  Using `--` attempts to change the variable `itt`, which can't be done here since it's an argument of your function.  All you need to do is replace `itt--` by `itt-1` and your code works fine.

P.S., if `a,b,m` are local variables, you can put them in the `{}` after `Module[`.

Answer (score 0):

Many ideas imported from procedural programming languages don't fit *Mathematica*. *Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language. If I have a definition:

```
foo[x_]:= an expression
```

That means "when you see `foo[something]`, evaluate `something` and then replace every `x` in `an expression` with the result and then evaluate `an expression`". So, if you evaluate `foo[1]`, all instances of `x` in `an expression` are replaced by `1` before evaluating `an expression`. Here, `x` is not a variable, but the name of a pattern that matches an argument.

Your `Module` isn't needed. `Module` is a symbol localization construct, but you are giving it an empty list of symbols to localize. The only thing it's doing is giving `Return` something to return from, but you don't need `Return`. `Return` doesn't do what you think it does. Don't use it until you understand what it does. Then you'll almost never use it.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to implement the bisection method is as follows.

```
      bisectStep[f_, {aStart_, bStart_}] :=
         Module[
            {a = N[Min[aStart, bStart]], b = N[Max[aStart, bStart]], fa, c, fc},
            fa = f[a];
            c = Mean[{a, b}]; fc = f[c];
            If[Sign[fa] != Sign[fc], b = c, a = c];
            {a, b}
        ]

      bisect[f_, a_, b_, \[Delta]_] := 
         Mean /@ NestWhileList[bisectStep[f, #] &, {1, 2}, (Subtract @@ Reverse[#] > \[Delta]) &]
```

It is used as follows:

```
      bisect[f, 1, 2, 0.00001]
```

Note that:

- the output consists of the midpoints of the successive intervals; and
- the stopping test is closeness of successive $x$-values (and not smallness of magnitude of function values).

If you want to see more than the default number of decimal places in the output, use `NumberForm`, e.g.:

```
      bisect[f, 1, 2, 0.00001] // NumberForm[#, 10] &
```